# Changing IonRow height in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm wondering if there's a better way to set the height of a grid row in Ionic 5 than simply overriding the default styles. Including an extra style to every row that I need to have a specified height is a bit tedious, and it seems like there should be a better way.

```
<IonGrid style={{ height: "100%" }}>
  <IonRow style={{height: "100%"}}>
    <IonCol>Hi</IonCol>
    <IonCol>Hi Again</IonCol>
    <IonCol>Hi A third time</IonCol>
  </IonRow>

</IonGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, for example in the `.scss` file add:

```
ion-grid {
    height: 120px;

    ion-row{
        height: 20px;
    }

    ion-col {
        border: 0.3px solid #f4f4f4;    
    }
}
```

And also "extra style":

```
ion-row.myHeight{
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Right, I've gathered that I can just override the component's default CSS, it just seems like a bit of an anti-pattern when we're talking about such a common dilemma. I was hoping that similar to how you can change the width of an ion column by simply passing in a size prop, you might be able to adjust the height of a row.

Comment: As I am not a english native speaker some times wonderings is like a huge doubts, But I can suggest you don't use style direct on the TAG like you did here: `<ion-row style={{height: "100%"}}>` It may seems an anti-pattern not scalable.